# Given three vectors. A vector $\vec{v}$ in the plane of these two vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

$(1)$ Let $\vec{a} = \hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}\;\;\; ,\vec{b}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}+\hat{k}\;\;,\vec{c}=\hat{i}-\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ be three vectors. A vector $\vec{v}$ in the plane of

$\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ and whose projection on $\vec{c}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is given by;

$(a)\;\; \hat{i}-3\hat{j}+3\hat{k}\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \hat{i}+3\hat{j}-3\hat{k}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(c)\;\; 3\hat{i}-\hat{j}+3\hat{k}\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; -3\hat{i}-3\hat{j}-\hat{k}.$

$(2)$ The vectors which are Coplanar with the vectors $\hat{i}+\hat{j}+2\hat{k}$ and $\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ and Perpendicular

with the vectors $\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ are

$(a)\;\; \hat{i}-\hat{j}\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \hat{j}-\hat{k}\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; \hat{j}-\hat{i}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(d)\;\; \hat{k}-\hat{j}$

Here $(a)\;,(b)\;,(c)\;,(d)$ are the options of Answers and more then one answer are corrects,

$\bf{My\; Try\; For \; (2):}$ Let $\vec{u}$ be a vector which are Coplanar with $\vec{a}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}+2\hat{k}$ and

$\vec{b}=\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k}$. So we can write it as $\vec{u}=\lambda \vec{a}+\mu \vec{b}$

So $\vec{u}=(\lambda+\mu)\hat{i}+(\lambda+2\mu)\hat{j}+(2\lambda+\mu)\hat{k}$ and Let $\vec{c}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ and Given $\vec{u}\cdot \vec{c}=0$

So $(\lambda+\mu)+(\lambda+2\mu)+(2\lambda+\mu)=0\Rightarrow 4\lambda+4\mu = 0\Rightarrow \lambda+\mu = 0$

So We get $\vec{u} = (\mu)\vec{j}+(\lambda)\vec{k}$. So which option is Right.

Plz help me, Thanks

and I did not understand If three vectors $\vec{a}\;,\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are coplanar,

Then how can I write $\vec{c} = \lambda \vec{a}+\mu \vec{b}. $ plz explain me.

and explain me that is it true that $2$ vectors are always Coplanar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say: "So We get $\vec{u} = (\mu)\vec{j}+(\lambda)\vec{k}$."

I agree with your logic up to the point of saying $\mu + \lambda = 0$, but the above statement isn't correct.  You introduced $\mu, \lambda$ differently at the beginning of your solution.

What it *does* imply is:

$$\vec{u} = \mu \vec{a} + \lambda \vec{b} = \mu (\vec{a} - \vec{b}) = \mu (\hat{i} + \hat{j} + 2\hat{k} - (\hat{i} + 2\hat{j} + \hat{k})) = \mu(-\hat{j} + \hat{k}).$$

This satisfies choices (b) and (d) with $\mu = \pm 1.$

Your questions at the end:

A geometric interpretation of the space spanned by two non-zero, linearly-independent $3$-vectors is a plane.  Therefore, any vector in that plane is expressible as a linear combination of those two spanning vectors.